# How to return a placeholder value in Hack?

Tags: hacklang

I am implementing a function that returns an `Awaitable<T>`-  but for the moment, I just want to return a placeholder value.

How do I accomplish this?

In rust, I'd so something like invoke the unimplemented!() macro - in java/python, I'd return null or raise an exception

Answer (score 2):

Control that always reaches an exception is a bottom type, so you can raise an exception to get any type:

```php
function unimplemented<T>(): T {
  throw new Exception("Unimplemented!");
}
```

If you want a usable placeholder *value* at runtime from your function, your only option is indeed `null` and a bunch of nullable annotations.